# Does the breathing apparatus worn by Adam Clay at the ending scene of Beekeeper exist in the real world?

Tags: props, beekeeper

I’m wondering what the breathing apparatus / scuba gear worn by character Adam Clay at the end of Beekeeper is.

It looks like a backpack worn on the belly, and has large tubes to breath through. Is this apparatus made up for the film or is it an existing model? What function does it have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, they exist

It's only a fleeting glimpse (apologies for the blurry capture) as shown but...

[image]

... this appears to be a Dräger [rebreather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebreather) (Wiki link) (specifically the Dräger LAR 8000) such as the one shown here.

[image]

> Dräger diving rebreathers are closed-circuit or semi-closed-circuit underwater rebreather, developed for military rebreather diving. Depending on the device, they are suitable for all requirements of shallow water diving, mine clearance and other operations.

[Drager website](https://www.draeger.com/en_uk/Safety/Defence-Security/Military-Diving)